# How to implement SSO with Joomla?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

We have following scenario. We have 2 websites one is in asp.net and 2nd in Joomla 1.5.

We want SSO from Joomla to ASP.Net site. Integration Flow as below:

1) Joomla site will have Menu Item named with "Join ASP.Net Site"
2) When Logged in User clicks on the Link we need to pass URL along with Logged in UserName in Joomla

E.g. www.abc.com?username=MNP  (here, MNP is username of the Joomla user who has clicked the link.) if user xyz is logged in then we need link as

www.abc.com?username=xyz

cCn somone provide the help how to create this?

Thanks

Regards
Jigar Shah

Now, my question is that

Answer (score 0):

Look at CAS from ja-sig which has clients for both .Net and for PHP
Joomla has a CAS authentication plugin.

Wiki docs at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Home

Comment: Please consider enhancing this response to actually provide an answer to the question, rather than simply a reference. Also consider adding a link to the resource in question - so that future searchers who are looking for a similar answer can be assisted. This kind of response merely makes SO one more link in a chain of searches, adding a new topic - rather than making it a useful stop to get an actual answer from.